# Javascript dropdown updates the price based on the users selection?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, select

I have a dropdown, which is like so:

```
    <select name="material>
    <option value="1">Wood</option>
    <option value="2">Metal</option>
    <option value="3">Plastic</option>
    </select>
```

Now based on the selection usind the value(id) I would like to update the price on the page using javascript (ie with posting). The values in the dropdown are the id for the material, I do have access to the price on the page as all of these details are returned as an array. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
var price = new Array('','$12.00','$18.00','$0.89');
$(function(){
    $('select[name=material]').change(function(){
       alert(price[$(this).val()]);
    }); 

    // Trigger on dom ready
    $('select[name=material]').change();
});
```